# Как лучше парсить html-страницы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html, парсер, php

Какой парсер выбрать и так далее.
Сама пользовалась для своих нужд `Simple_Html_Dom`. Но беда в том, что если не для мини нужд он нужен, то плох, так как с ним страницы грузятся до ужасов долго

Comment: Могу обучить регулярке ))

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк Собственно, я ответил на Ваш вопрос:[Как ускорить парсер?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/177469/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: Как вариант - [phpQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для небольших задач можно использовать парсинг посредством регулярных выражений. Основной плюс: высокая скорость работы, а минус, это порой сложность составления.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Котик: ура, ещё один человек на сайте не одобряет парсинг HTML регулярными выражениями

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать и @VladD: думаю это дело вкуса и зависит от конкретной задачи. никто не претендует на универсальность метода, тем не менее думаю использование регулярных выражений это частая практика.

Answer (score 2):

Можно закачать страницу в DomDocument и парсить как XML, но порой структура сайта не всегда отвечает требованиям XML, так что могут возникнуть проблемы, но большинство сайтов таким способом парсятся. И я, как и [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis), бы порекомендовал phpQuery

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки если нужно распарить не слишком много контента. Очень медленные. Есть готовые парсеры на пхп, но они еще медленнее работают (субъективно).

Answer (score 1):

Если структура сайта удобная, то пользуюсь nokogiri, если не получается - регулярками.